# small test_set xgb predict

Tags: xgboost, predict

i would like to ask a question about a problem that i have for the last couple days.
First of all i am a beginner in machine learning and this is my first time using the XGBoost algorithm so excuse me for any mistakes I have done.

I trained my model to predict whether a log file is malicious or not. After i save and reload my model on a different session i use the predict function which seems to be working normally ( with a few deviations in probabilities but that is another topic, I know I, have seen it in another topic )

The problem is this: Sometimes when i try to predict a "small" csv file after load it seems to be broken predicting only the Zero label, even for indexes that are categorized correct previously.
For example, i load a dataset containing 20.000 values , the predict() is working. I keep only the first 5 of these values using pandas drop, again its working. If i save the 5 values on a different csv and reload it its not working. The same error happens if i just remove by hand all indexes (19.995) and save file only with 5 remaining.

I would bet it is a size of file problem but when i drop the indexes on the dataframe through pandas it seems to be working
Also the number 5 ( of indexes ) is for example purpose the same happens if I delete a large portion of the dataset.
I first came up with this problem after trying to verify by hand some completely new logs, which seem to be classified correctly if thrown into the big csv file but not in a new file on their own.

### Here is my load and predict code

```
##IMPORTS
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
from datetime import datetime
from langid.langid import LanguageIdentifier, model
import langid
import time
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from ggplot import ggplot, aes, geom_line
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from collections import defaultdict
import pickle
df = pd.read_csv('big_test.csv')

df3 = pd.read_csv('small_test.csv')

#This one is necessary for the loaded_model
class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def init(self, column_list):
        self.column_list = column_list

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, x):
        if len(self.column_list) == 1:
            return x[self.column_list[0]].values
        else:
            return x[self.column_list].to_dict(orient='records')

loaded_model = joblib.load('finalized_model.sav')
result = loaded_model.predict(df)
print(result)

df2=df[:5]
result2 = loaded_model.predict(df2)
print(result2)

result3 = loaded_model.predict(df3)
print(result3)
```

The results i get are these:

[1 0 1 ... 0 0 0]

[1 0 1 0 1]

[0 0 0 0 0]

I can provide any code even from training or my dataset if necessary.

*EDIT: I use a pipeline for my data. I tried to reproduce the error after using xgb to fit the iris data and i could not. Maybe there is something wrong with my pipeline? the code is below :

```
df = pd.read_csv('big_test.csv')
# df.info()


# Split Dataset
attributes = ['uri','code','r_size','DT_sec','Method','http_version','PenTool','has_referer', 'Lang','LangProb','GibberFlag' ]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[attributes], df['Scan'], test_size=0.2, 
stratify=df['Scan'], random_state=0)

x_train, x_dev, y_train, y_dev = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, 
                                                  stratify=y_train, random_state=0)
# print('Train:', len(y_train), 'Dev:', len(y_dev), 'Test:', len(y_test))

# set up graph function
def plot_precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_pred_scores):
    precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_pred_scores)
    return ggplot(aes(x='recall', y='precision'), 
                  data=pd.DataFrame({"precision": precision, "recall": recall})) + geom_line()


# XGBClassifier

class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, column_list):
        self.column_list = column_list
        
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, x):
        if len(self.column_list) == 1:
            return x[self.column_list[0]].values
        else:
            return x[self.column_list].to_dict(orient='records')


count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(1, 2), min_df=10)
dict_vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
xgb = XGBClassifier(seed=0)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("feature_union", FeatureUnion([
        ('text_features', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ColumnSelector(['uri'])), 
            ('count_vectorizer', count_vectorizer)
        ])),
        ('categorical_features', Pipeline([
            ('selector', ColumnSelector(['code','r_size','DT_sec','Method','http_version','PenTool','has_referer', 'Lang','LangProb','GibberFlag' ])),
            ('dict_vectorizer', dict_vectorizer)
        ]))
    ])),
    ('xgb', xgb)
])

pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)

filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
joblib.dump(pipeline, filename)
```

Comment: Are you sure the line:- `df2=df[:5]` is doing what you think its doing? Please provide the csv files as it is.

Comment: i think it saves as dataframe only the first 5 elements of df .

Comment: I have a few notes that might help:

I also the same debug approach with the same csv file without pipeline or count_vectorizer using a model with only the other attributes as numbers and it was correct.
I tried the same  approach with completely other XGB classifiers and csv files, also without pipeline, and it worked correctly. 

I think it comes down to count vectorizer or the pipeline containing it, not sure

Comment: Please also link the small.csv

Comment: its a copy paste of the first n-elements of big.csv . 
Select the first 5 and copy them to a new one named 'small.csv'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats due to different dtypes in big and small file.

When you do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('big_test.csv')
```

The dtypes are these:

```
print(df.dtypes)

# Output
uri              object
code             object   # <== Observe this
r_size           object   # <== Observe this
Scan              int64
...
...
...
```

Now when you do:

```
df3 = pd.read_csv('small_test.csv')
```

the dtypes are changed:

```
print(df3.dtypes)

# Output
uri              object
code              int64   # <== Now this has changed
r_size            int64   # <== Now this has changed
Scan              int64
...
...
```

You see, pandas will try to determine the dtypes of the columns by itself. When you load the big_test.csv, there are some values in `code` and `r_size` column which are of string types, due to this whole column dtype is changed to string, which is not done in small_test.csv.

Now due to this change, the dictVectorizer encodes the data in a different way than before and the features are changed, and hence the results are also changed.

If you do this:

```
df3[['code', 'r_size']] = df3[['code', 'r_size']].astype(str)
```

and then call the `predict()`, the results are same again.